# Запись в скобках после for

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает запись в скобках после for:

```
function listToArray(list) {
  let array = [];
  for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    array.push(node.value);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Нипривычно видеть такую запись после, например,

```
for (i=0; i<array.length; i++)
```

Comment: Что скажите на это `for(;;){}`?

Comment: Вот мне интересно. Доброхоты, которые бросились разжевывать синтаксис `for` лентяю, они действительно считают, что StackOverflow нужен для таких вещей? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: @Igor почему лентяй, может быть просто он не задумывался над этим, многие начинают программировать так сказать интуитивно, без прямых и полных знаний... copy paste... это и у меня бывает иногда, но всё реже. Я думаю автору только плюс, за то что он помогает задуматься над такими вещами. Всё таки полноценные знания лучше чем урывочные и интуитивное программирование.

Comment: Кстати применение очень интересное... в некоторых современных языках для классической записи уже стараются делать `for(i in 1..10)`, оно более интуитивно понятно.

Comment: Ага, в новых языках таких как Pascal, например: `for i:= 1 to 10 do`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Классический цикл

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  doSomething();
}
```

эквивалентен такому циклу

```
i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
  doSomething();
  i++;
}
```

Таким образом, ваша запись эквивалентна следующей

```
function listToArray(list) {
  let array = [];
  let node = list;
  while (node) {
    array.push(node.value);
    node = node.rest;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Можно добавить еще эквивалент для `for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` (для наглядности)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 7):

Первое выражение в `for` выполняется единожды перед началом цикла. Будь то инициализация переменной `i`, или создание переменной `node`.

Второе выражение является условием выполнения `for`. Если оно `false`, то цикл обрывается.

Третье выражение выполняется в конце каждой итерации цикла. Будь то инкремент `i`, или же запись `node.rest` в переменную `node`.

Как-то так. Вроде не сложно.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: можно добавить что единожды перед циклом.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да, тоже об этом подумал